# d3 conditional text color (within a colored rect)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have text that I want to append inside rects from a data set using d3. The rects have a color fill from an object that maps a company name to a color. What I started to notice is that I also need some kind of logic for the text fill or else the text will be hard to read on darker rects (since I'm using default black). Take this little snippet for instance:

```js
var margins = {top:100, left:80, bottom:40, right:20};
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var data = [
  {'fmc': 'UBS', 'value': 2308.78},
 {'fmc': 'Fidelity', 'value': 976.76},
 {'fmc': 'JP Morgan', 'value': 837.19},
 {'fmc': 'Value Partners', 'value': 787.39}
];

var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([150,2500])
    .range([20,130]);

var colorMap = {
  'UBS':"#003366",
  'Fidelity':"#366092",
  'JP Morgan':"#4f81b9",
  'Value Partners':"#95b3d7"
};

let counterRect = 0,
  counterText = 0;

    var column = graphGroup.selectAll('.column')
        .data(data)
        .attr('class', 'column')
      .enter().append("g");

    column.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return heightScale(d.value)
        })
        .attr('x', function(d) {return 10})
        .attr('y', function(d, i) {
          let previous = counterRect;
          return (counterRect += heightScale(d.value)+2, previous)
        })
        .style('fill',function(d,i) {return colorMap[d.fmc]});

        column.append("text")
          .attr('x', function(d) {return 75})
          .attr('y', function(d, i) {
            let previous = counterText;
            return (counterText += heightScale(d.value)+2, previous + (heightScale(d.value)/2))
          })
          .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.fmc;
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

To keep it simple, let's suppose I want `UBS`, `Fidelity`, and `JP Morgan` to be `"white"` and `Value Partners` to be `"black"`. In my real application, this solution would need to be scalable, because I'm dealing with over 50 colors. Is there any approach to solve if the text should be white or black based on the rect's color, other than brute force/ adding a bool beforehand?

I know that `d3.select(this).datum()` can return the datum of the element, so that can find an anonymous rect's color, but that doesn't help us if we don't know what to do with that color in terms of how to use that info when it comes to choosing white or black font fill.

Comment: @altocumulus oops, yea, that's not right. Turns out one of the quote marks disappeared on me.

Comment: I like the approach laid out in [*Switch font color for different backgrounds with CSS*](https://css-tricks.com/switch-font-color-for-different-backgrounds-with-css/) which solely relies on CSS. I am not sure if it is applicable to your particular problem, but it may be worth giving it a try.